# Dryer calls for 1/8" NPT plug - why not just direct connection?

Tags: dryer, gas, natural-gas

Any ideas why this dryer gas connection diagram calls for the "1/8" NPT Pipe Plug" - why isn't it just calling for a direct connection to the gas supply instead of having something that T's off with a plug?

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I checked another one at (essentially) random - a Whirlpool - and the instructions (different diagram, so presumably a different model) have the same 1/8" NPT Plug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "T" with the 1/8" threaded connection is for checking the down stream gas appliance and piping for any gas leakage and to check the gas pressure to the device. I would rather use a "T" with a 1/4" threaded connection. It eliminates the need for the manufacturer to supply a "test connection", and saves them a couple cents.